# Can I get position and velocity data from an IMU unit? I'm lost :(

Tags: sensors, imu, sensor-fusion

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this question; I'm from a totally different field and english is not my first language. Nevertheless, I'll give it a shot, any advice will be greatly appreciated(maybe even recommendations of other places to ask)

I'm currently working with Olympic Weightlifting athletes, and an important aspect of weightlifting technique is bar path(observed from the side) and barbell velocity.
[blue line shows bar path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klib0.png)
I used to see bar path with a motion tracking software called Dartfish. However, picking the exact spot to track by hand, the time-consuming motion tracking process itself, and the fact that I cannot give immediate feedback to athletes is a disadvantage.

Then I stumbled upon IMU devices, and it seemed potentially useful for what I'm doing right now. If only I can get barbell position and velocity from IMU data, I think it might be a game changer for our training. However without understanding of physics/mathematics/programming it has been quite tough for me to learn anything.

Thanks for reading this long story, I hope I can get somewhere with this idea. Or would it be better for me to stick to the traditional program? I also contacted a sports kinematics researcher but I'm waiting for his reply.

*I'm still learning basic terminology and principles. I think I'm supposed to integrate the acceleration data, apply "sensor fusion", correct errors using "filter techniques". I've seen acceleration data in CSV form, but not in graphs.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.